# Simple Curl -H in R

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I want to do

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic YOUR_API_KEY" -d '{"classifier_id":155, "value":"TEST"}' "https://www.machinelearningsite.com/language/classify"
```

I tried

```
  h = getCurlHandle(header = TRUE, userpwd = YOUR_API_KEY, netrc = TRUE)
out <- getURL("https://www.machinelearningsite.com/language/classify?classifier_id=155&value=TEST", curl=h,ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
```

but it says method not allowed

Comment: Which OS do you have?

Comment: Windows 8.1. In know you could invoke a linux command, but that wont work on Windows so I need a generic solution

Answer (score 6):

It's much easier to translate `curl` command-line arguments into `httr` calls:

```
library(httr)

result <- GET("https://www.machinelearningsite.com/language/classify",
              add_headers(Authorization=sprintf("Basic %s", YOUR_API_KEY),
              query=list(classifier_id=155, value="TEST")))
```

ideally, `YOUR_API_KEY` would be an environment variable, so you can change that to:

```
result <- GET("https://www.machinelearningsite.com/language/classify",
              add_headers(Authorization=sprintf("Basic %s", Sys.getenv("YOUR_API_KEY")),
              query=list(classifier_id=155, value="TEST")))
```

You can then do:

```
content(result)
```

To retrieve the actual data.

Comment: Error in add_headers(Authorization = sprintf("Basic %s", key), query = params(classifier_id = model,  : 
  could not find function "params"

Comment: I tried     out <- GET("https://www.classifier.io/language/classify",
                  add_headers(Authorization=sprintf("Basic %s", "abcdefg"),
                              query=list(classifier_id="1234", value="TESTtetx")))

Comment: Error: is.character(headers) is not TRUE

Comment: aye. it should have been `list`. fixed it. I can't help more without a valid site to test against. you can even look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22672642/1457051 for another sample with `httr` and `add_headers`

Comment: I think you can use `authenticate()` instead of manually adding headers like a savage

Comment: That validation is good though. I thought was much when looking at the command line incantation. Sites really should standardize.